# Strange space on grid.arrange plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I am trying to add footnote to grid.arrange graph. I presented my idea in this reproducible example:
)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

summary(anscombe)

p1 <- ggplot(anscombe) + geom_point(aes(x1, y1), color = "darkorange", size = 3) + theme_bw() 

p2 <- ggplot(anscombe) + geom_point(aes(x2, y2), color = "darkorange", size = 3) + theme_bw()

p3 <- ggplot(anscombe) + geom_point(aes(x3, y3), color = "darkorange", size = 3) + theme_bw()

p4 <- ggplot(anscombe) + geom_point(aes(x4, y4), color = "darkorange", size = 3) + theme_bw() 

title <- textGrob("Some title",
              gp=gpar(fontsize=20,fontface=2))

source1<- textGrob("Source: https://rpubs.com/neilfws/91339",
              hjust=0,x=0,y=1,
              gp=gpar(fontsize=10,fontface=3))

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, sub = source1), top = title)
```

This code generates that picture:

[image]

with huge space below the graphs. How to get rid off of that? Why is it created?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `bottom` instead of `sub`:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, bottom = source1), top = title)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Simplifying a bit, `grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, bottom = source1, top = title)` also works.

Comment: yep, the reason for the white space was that it considered the subtitle as just another grob to arrange, thereby making a 3x2 layout (with equal heights by default). It's a problem with functions having `...` as first argument, they will silently ignore names that don't match the following arguments.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use this code:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, sub = source1), top = title, heights = c(50,-15))
```

And modify the heights until you have the deserved spacing. I achieved this only setting that parameter with showed values:

[image]